# ZF2 Dependency Injection in Ancesor Objects

Tags: dependencies, code-injection, zend-framework2

My goal is to use DI in ancestor objects using setters so I have a common DI for ancestor objects. e.g. an abstract model class my other models inherit from, preconfigured with an entity manager etc.

So far, after configuring the ancestor and creating it with DI successfully, changing it to an abstract class, then instantiating an ancestor of that class the DI for the abstract (whether set to abstract or not) doesn't run.

`namespace Stuki;`

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

# abstract
class Model {
    protected $em;

    public function setEm(EntityManager $em) {
        $this->em = $em;
    }
}
```

The DI for this class

`'di' => array(`

```
    'instance' => array(

        'Stuki\Model' => array(
            'parameters' => array(
                'em' => 'doctrine_em'
            )        
        ),
```

The above class and DI will work.  But I want that to run on ancestor objects so

`namespace Stuki\Model;`

```
use Stuki\Model as StukiModel;

class Authentication extends StukiModel {
    public function getIdentity() {
        return 'ƒß'; #die('get identity');
    }
}

$auth = $e->getTarget()->getLocator()->get('Stuki\Model\Authentication');
```

The last line, $auth = , doesn't run the DI.

How can I setup DI for ancestor objects, without using introspection?

Comment: From a Doctrine entity point of view, entities should not be entitymanager aware. I guess you're using SpiffyDoctrineORM for zf2 doctrine support?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my assumptions were incorrect when I replied via Meetup ;)

The crux of your problem is you are configuring Stuki\Model to take an EntityManager in the InstanceManager, but asking Di for a Stuki\Authentication.

You can switch to constructor injections...this works but I don't really like having to define constructor in ancestor class:

```
class EntityManager {

}

# abstract
abstract class Model {
    protected $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em) {
        $this->em = $em;
    }
}

class Authentication extends Model {
    public function getIdentity() {
        return 'ƒß'; #die('get identity');
    }
}

$di = new Zend\Di\Di();
$im = new Zend\Di\InstanceManager();
$di->setInstanceManager($im);
$auth = $di->get('Authentication');
var_dump($auth);
```

One thing to note, in both our examples, Di still needs to use introspection to discover things like the instantiator, methods, and method params. The only way to avoid introspection at runtime is to precompile: http://packages.zendframework.com/docs/latest/manual/en/zend.di.definition.html#zend.di.definition.compilerdefinition.